# Receiving copies of emails intended for someone else

Tags: email

I hope I can explain this right. I am receiving emails that are sent to someone else. Some are replies to emails they have sent and others are from sites that person has subscribed to.  This person is using Mac mail and I am using Yahoo mail. My email address is not showing in the email but if I reply to all, I get copied.  Does anyone know how this has happened and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that these messages are originating from more than one user.

Contact the mail host (@____.com) and let them know. It sounds like a forward error that can be blocked/resolved.

The good thing is that this sounds like they have the compromised account (although there is no guarantee that they don't see your mail).

For clarification: are you recieving a copy of a message that the person using MacMail receives as well? Or are you the only one the sent message is addressed to?

Comment: Yes they are coming from more than one user. I don't understand the 2nd comment. I am receiving a copy of a message that the person using MacMail receives. Her name is the only one showing in the 'to' section. My email address shows no where. I know this person.